# Spark refuse to zip RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following exception at the last line running the code below with Spark

*org.apache.spark.SparkException: Can only zip RDDs with same number of elements in each partition*

```
val rdd1 = anRDD
val rdd2 = AnotherRDD

println(rdd1.count() == rdd2.count()) // Write true
val nparts = rdd1.getNumPartitions + rdd2.getNumPartitions

val rdd1Bis = rdd1.repartition(nparts) // Try to repartition (useless)
val rdd2Bis = rdd2.repartition(nparts)

val zipped = rdd1Bis.zip(rdd2Bis)
println(zipped.count())
```

What is wrong ?

PS: it works if I collect rdd1 and rdd2 before zipping but i need to keep them as RDD

Comment: If you skip the repartition, does the zip work?

Comment: I think there's no guarantee that a repartition will end up with the same number of elements in each partition, only the same number of similar sized partitions. Can you use `zipPartitions`? " Zip this RDD's partitions with one (or more) RDD(s) and return a new RDD by applying a function to the zipped partitions. Assumes that all the RDDs have the *same number of partitions*, but does *not* require them to have the same number of elements in each partition"

Comment: Are RDD1 and RDD2 derived from the same RDD somewhere upstream (above this code snippet)? Zipping only works if the partitions all "line up", so to speak. This means each RDD has the same number of partitions and the same number of rows within each corresponding partition. This works when you have 2 RDDs derived from a single RDD, and no shuffling in between create the two RDDs and then trying to zip them back up (e,g, only `map` and `filter` operations).

Comment: In addition I think there is no guarantee that the data in the RDD before and after the lib are in the same order, so my zip is a potential bug. I think i will have to find another way to do this

Answer (score 2):

A solution could be to zip with a join:

```
val rdd1Bis = rdd1.zipWithIndex.map((x) =>(x._2, x._1))
val rdd2Bis = rdd2.zipWithIndex.map((x) =>(x._2, x._1))
val zipped = rdd1Bis.join(rdd2Bis).map(x => x._2)
```

Answer (score 0):

it works check this:Please reply with what part it fails for you

```
val list1 = List("a","b","c","d")
val list1 = List("a","b","c","d")
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(list1)
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(list2)
```

Executing ur code :

```
val nparts = rdd1.getNumPartitions + rdd2.getNumPartitions
val rdd1Bis = rdd1.repartition(nparts) // Try to repartition (useless)
val rdd2Bis = rdd2.repartition(nparts)
val zipped = rdd1Bis.zip(rdd2Bis)
```

Result:

```
 println(zipped.count())
 4
 zipped.foreach(println)
 (a,a)
 (b,b)
 (c,c)
 (d,d)
```

Comment: With that small a data set I suspect any issues with repartitioning won't show up. Can you give it a (much) bigger list to work with?

Comment: This will work because your lists are the same. In my example rdd1 and rdd2 are based originally on the same RDD but one of them  (let say rdd1) has been transformed with an external library. At the end of the transformation, it still has the same number of elements inside.

Comment: I'd give you an example where this won't work if you want, try setting the numbers of partitions for rdd1 to 3 and rdd2 to 4.

Comment: @eliasah I agree it wont work if u change the partitions but in the problem above mentioned partitions are forced to be same using repartition.

Comment: even after re-partitioning to the same numbers of partitions that won't work.

Comment: @Benjamin solutions looks better as of now will try with bigger list. I believe as long as we have equal elements in partitions an equal partitions this should work .